# is possible to set MAC address while provisioning the VM through powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

When provisioning a VM on Azure. Is there a way to hardcore set the MAC address using PowerShell?

Comment: No, it isn't possible! What is your use case though? why do you want to do that?

Comment: Yes and No. Yes, you can do it by custom script extension. No, if you do that, your VM will be disconnected from the internet, and you will not be able to access it.

Comment: @JackZeng Which is much closer to no than yes ;)

Comment: I am providing a possible way to achieve it, and there may be a corresponding way to manipulate the network interface of the VM, so that the VM can be reconnected to internet again.

Comment: From the REST API of Network Interface Card, I can see that there is a property "macAddress". I am not sure if it can be changed or not.

Comment: basically to a fix a VM with boot problems, a pfsense appliance will run the initalizaiton script again everytime it detects a change in the network interface card

Comment: added an answer below. let me know what you think? it seems to be a dead end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below resolution online. But, I was advised that we will surely run into the same error. Because, we don’t know what the mac address will be for the VM when we create it next time around.

**Attempted Resolution**:

As console access is not an available feature yet in Azure, you will basically be mounting the problematic OS disk as a data disk on a working VM to correct changes to the file system configuration:

A = Original VM (Inaccessible/errored VM)  B = New VM (New Temp VM)

1) Stop VM A via the Azure management portal

2) Delete VM A BUT select “keep the attached disks”

3) Once the lease is cleared, attach the Data Disk from A to VM B via the Azure Portal, Virtual Machines, Select “A”, Attach Disk

4) On VM “B” eventually the disk will attach and you can then mount it.

5) Locate the drive name to mount, on VM “B” look in relevant log file note each linux is slightly different.

```
grep SCSI /var/log/kern.log (ubuntu)
```

6) Mount the attached disk onto mountpoint /tempmount

```
df -h
mkdir /tempmount
mount /dev/sdc1 /tempmount
df –h
```

7) Change into /etc directory where the original OS disk from resides

```
cd /tempmount/etc/
cp fstab fstab_orig
```

8) Now that you have made a backup of you fstab you can proceed to make the changes you require using vi, nano or your preferred text editor.

```
vi fstab
cd /
umount /tempmount
```

9) Detach the disk from VM B via the management portal

10) Recreate the original VM A (Create VM from Gallery, Select My Disks) you will see the Disk referring to VM A – Select the original Cloud Service name.